# arithmetic manipulations in YAML configuration file with omegaconf

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Currently, I have this configuration file which I'm using as an input to *hydra/omegaconf*

```
db: 
  range: 
    - -10
    - 10
```

Since the values in the *range* field are related by simple algebra, I'm looking for a way to encode this into the configuration file.
Conceptually, I  would like to have something like this:

```
db: 
  db_val: 10
  range: 
    - (-1) * ${..db_val}
    - ${..db_val}
```

But this not seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom [interpolation resolver](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.0_branch/usage.html#custom-interpolations):

```py
def symmetric_range(a):
  return (-a, a)

OmegaConf.register_resolver("symmetric_range", symmetric_range)
```

and then in your config file:

```yaml
db: 
  range: ${symmetric_range:10}
```

or

```yaml
db:
  db_val: 10
  range: ${symmetric_range:${db_val}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to register an `eval` resolver

```
OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("eval", eval)
```

and then in your config file:

```
db: 
  db_val: 10
  range: 
    - ${eval:'(-1) * ${..db_val}'}
    - ${..db_val}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operations in the OmegaConf configs are not currently supported.
There is [feature request](https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/issues/91) to support it though.